# How to make Dependency Injection with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

How can I know the type of the parameter in the constructor to make `riverpod` works like `get_it`, so I don't have to pass `ref.read(x)` every time, so I just have to pass `locator()`?

I'm just passing `ref.read(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer: For the sake of simplicity I base my answer on `AsyncNotifier` and its `AsyncNotifierProvider` only.*

First, let's find the way people inject dependencies to AsyncNotifier.

- [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75781957/1714102) proposes to use `ref` to get the desired dependency. Ok.
- [Official Riverpod AsyncNotifier 2.0.0 documentation](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider) shows the similar way, but with `@riverpod` annotation, which obscures the main idea a bit. But it's ok.
- The simplest example I've found is [here](https://github.com/bizz84/async_notifier_example_riverpod/blob/6b2b23c1c595d94e5d3cce45969c858be9fd97cd/lib/notifiers/auth_controller_manual.dart). Basically, you use `ref` every time you need the dependency. Fine.

And it is fundamentally weird for me to inject things this way. Such a code for somebody with Java/Kotlin/many other languages background looks like a lack of Dependency Injection. The question is "How can I know the type of **the parameter in the constructor** (...)?". Because this is the nicest way of inject things - via constructor, right?

Not necessarily in Riverpod! To understand why Riverpod proposes so weird attitude we should go back to the roots. I learned that Dependency Injection has two main reasons, and that constructors naturally supports those ideas:

1. constraint the amount of code changes in class A due to a change in its class B dependency.
2. gives easy way to substitute dependencies with fakes or mocks to makes tests easy.

Riverpod can support the ideas without constructors and that's the point.

1. `Providers` separate the concern of changing the code of class A due to its class B dependency change
2. You can substitute the dependencies with the mock/fake ones thanks to `overrideWithValue`.

This is how I perceive it. To answer the question: use [manual](https://github.com/bizz84/async_notifier_example_riverpod/blob/6b2b23c1c595d94e5d3cce45969c858be9fd97cd/lib/notifiers/auth_controller_manual.dart) or [generated](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider) attitude with refs.

Answer (score 0):

With the Riverpod 2.0 update you can use the `NotifierProvider` and `AsyncNotifierProvider`. The `ref` is now inside a class extended from `Notifier` and `AsyncNotifier` respectively.

Example:

```dart
// TagPageState - these are the different states of the `TagPage` page

class TagPageNotifier extends AutoDisposeNotifier<TagPageState> {
  TagPageNotifier();

  static final i = AutoDisposeNotifierProvider<TagPageNotifier, TagPageState>(
    TagPageNotifier.new,
  );

  @override
  TagPageState build() {
     
    // inside the `build` method you can use `ref.watch` or `ref.listen`
    
    state = const TagPageState.loading();

    /// fetch all tags
    final List<TagUi> tags = ref.watch(tagsProvider);

    if (tags.isEmpty) return const TagPageState.empty();

    return TagPageState.data(tags);
  }

  void deleteTag() {
    // you have access to `ref` in any methods
    ref.read(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/providers#why-use-providers

Answer (score 0):

This is usage of AsyncNotifier without code generation.

```
final localStorageProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<LocalStorageNotifier, LocalStorage>(
        () => LocalStorageNotifier());

class LocalStorageNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<LocalStorageImpl> {
  @override
  FutureOr<LocalStorageImpl> build() async {
    return LocalStorageImpl(await SharedPreferences.getInstance());
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
After further research I decided that this approach is more appropriate to my project.

```
final localStorageProvider =
    Provider<LocalStorage>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      localStorageProvider.overrideWithValue(LocalStorageImpl(prefs))
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}
```